# Lens equivalent of evolve or lens to multiple values

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

It's my understanding is lenses are functions that contain the means to `get` and `set` values.

I have this helper function:

```js
const overEach = uncurryN(3, 
  fn => lenses =>
    lenses.length > 0 ? 
    compose(...map(flip(over)(fn), lenses)) : 
    identity
);
```

in use

```js
const annual = ["yearsPlayed", "age"];
const annualInc = overEach(
  inc,
  map(lensProp, annual),
);

console.log(
  annualInc({
    jersey: 148,
    age: 10,
    yearsPlayed: 2,
    id: 3.14159
  })
);
```

The output:

```js
{
    jersey: 41,
    age: 11,
    yearsPlayed: 3,
    id: 3.14159
}
```

This is interesting because (like evolve), I can define how something of a certain shape is meant to change. This is better than evolve because it gives me a clean separation of concern about the shape of my data and what I'm doing to it. This is worse than evolve because it creates an intermediate value that I never use. The more lenses I have, the more intermediate values I create.

```js
{
    jersey: 148,
    age: 10,
    yearsPlayed: 3,
    id: 3.14159
}
```

---

I'd be curious to know if there's a way to define a lens that points to more than one value. `compose(lenseIndices([1,7,9]), lensProp('parents'), lensIndex(0))` Might point to the first parent of three different people.

It seems to me this really should be possible, but I don't know what to search and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel (Especially as I haven't been in the weeds with lenses yet), if it can and also has been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd be curious to know if there's a way to define a lens that points to more than one value.

The intuition we should have for a "lens" is that it "focuses" on a particular part of a data structure.  So really, no.  A lens is all about working with something specific.  (But see the update below that demonstrates that this something specific does *not* have to be a single property.)

[Ramda's issue #2457](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2547) discusses the uses of lenses in greater detail.

---

I don't think I agree with your interpretation of additional flexibilities your function provides compared to `evolve`.  In fact, if I were to implement it, I would probably do so atop `evolve`, with something like this:

```js
const {evolve, fromPairs, inc} = R

const overEach = (fn, names) =>
  evolve (fromPairs (names .map (name => [name, fn])))

const annualInc = overEach (inc, ["yearsPlayed", "age"])

console .log (annualInc ({
  jersey: 148,
  age: 10,
  yearsPlayed: 2,
  id: 3.14159
}))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

And `evolve` lets you easily choose different functions for different properties, allows you to nest transformations, and is extremely declarative.

`overEach` simply allows us to apply the same transformation function to many different nodes.  This is useful, of course, but seems likely less common than the normal cases of `evolve`.

## Update

I want to clarify something I said above.  While lenses *focus* on a particular part of a data structure, that does not mean that they can only affect one *field* or *property* of an object.  We need to think of this more holistically. That part can be multiple fields, possibly with subfields.  I think this is easiest to describe through an example.

Let's imagine you have your polished `box` function used to describe a box on the cartesian grid.  It has read-only *position*, *width*, and *height* properties, and methods to move it, scale it, list the corners, find the areas  And all of these are properly functional, returning new boxes rather than mutating the original.  You're pretty happy with this code:

```js
const box = (l, t, w, h) => ({
  move: (dx, dy) => box (l += dx, t += dy, w, h),
  scale: (dw, dh) => box (l, t, w *= dw, h *= dh),
  area: () => w * h,
  get position () { return {x: l, y: t} },
  get width () { return w},
  get height () { return h },
  corners: () => [{x: l, y: t}, {x: l + w, y: t}, {x: l + w, y: t + h}, {x: l, y: t + h}],
  toString: () => `Box (left: ${l}, top: ${t}, height: ${h}, width: ${w})`
})
```

But now you want to apply your tools to a new situation, where you have widgets that look like this:

```js
const widget = {
  topLeft: {x: 126, y: 202},
  bottomRight: {x: 776, y: 682},
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderWidth: 3,
  backgroundUrl: 'http://example.com/img.png',
  // ...
}
```

While the `topRight` and `bottomLeft` points are a compatible way of describing the rectangle, you would have to rewrite a pile of code that already handle boxes to deal with these new widgets.  Moreover, boxes seem the logical view of the situation.  Heights and widths seem much more relevant than the bottom-right corners.  Here we can use lenses to deal with the concerns.  That is, we can think entirely in boxes, extracting a box from the widget, adjusting the values by adjusting the box.  We just need to write a lens to do it:

```js
const boxLens = lens (
  ({topLeft: {x: x1, y: y1}, bottomRight: {x: x2, y: y2}}) => 
    box (x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1),
  ({position: {x, y}, width, height}, widget) => ({
    ...widget, 
    topLeft: {x, y}, 
    bottomRight: {x: x + width, y: y + height}
  })
)
```

Now we can deal with the position and extent of our widget as though it were described by a box:

```js
view (boxLens, widget) .toString ()
//=> "Box (left: 126, top: 202, height: 480, width: 650)"

view (boxLens, widget) .corners ()
//=> [{x: 126, y: 202}, {x: 776, y: 202}, {x: 776, y: 682}, {x: 126, y: 682}]

set (boxLens, box (200, 150, 1600, 900), widget)
//=> {topLeft: {x: 200, y: 150}, bottomRight: {x: 1800, y: 1050}, borderColor: "red", ...}

over (boxLens, box => box .scale (.5, .5), widget)
//=> {topLeft: {x: 126, y: 202}, bottomRight: {x: 451, y: 442}, borderColor: "red", ...}

const moveWidget = (dx, dy) => 
  over(boxLens, box => box .move (dx, dy))

moveWidget (10, 50) (widget)
//=> {topLeft: {x: 136, y: 252}, bottomRight: {x: 786, y: 732}, borderColor: "red", ...}
```

You can confirm this in the following snippet:

```js
const {lens, view, set, over} = R

const box = (l, t, w, h) => ({
  move: (dx, dy) => box (l += dx, t += dy, w, h),
  scale: (dw, dh) => box (l, t, w *= dw, h *= dh),
  area: () => w * h,
  get position () { return {x: l, y: t} },
  get width () { return w},
  get height () { return h },
  corners: () => [{x: l, y: t}, {x: l + w, y: t}, {x: l + w, y: t + h}, {x: l, y: t + h}],
  toString: () => `Box (left: ${l}, top: ${t}, height: ${h}, width: ${w})`
})

const boxLens = lens(
  ({topLeft: {x: x1, y: y1}, bottomRight: {x: x2, y: y2}}) => box (x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1),
  ({position: {x, y}, width, height}, widget) => ({
    ...widget, 
    topLeft: {x, y}, 
    bottomRight: {x: x + width, y: y + height}
  })
)

const widget = {
  topLeft: {x: 126, y: 202},
  bottomRight: {x: 776, y: 682},
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderWidth: 3,
  backgroundUrl: 'http://example.com/img.png',
  // ...
}

console .log (
  view (boxLens, widget) .toString ()
)
console .log (
  view (boxLens, widget) .corners ()
)
console .log (
  set (boxLens, box (200, 150, 1600, 900), widget)
)
console .log (
  over (boxLens, box => box .scale (.5, .5), widget)
)

const moveWidget = (dx, dy) => 
  over(boxLens, box => box .move (dx, dy))

console .log (
  moveWidget (10, 50) (widget)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

#### The Point

This shows that we *can* use lenses to deal with more than one field at a time, as Mrk Sef's self-answer also explains.  But we have to deal with them in some way isomorphic to the original.  This is actually a very powerful use of lenses.  But this does not imply that we can simply use them to work on arbitrary properties.

Comment: The way I see it (right now at least) is the flexibility of overEach comes from it composing a list of lenses. It doesn't need the shape of what it's given. If `overEach` takes a list of names, then we're very constrained on the type of data structure we're working over (no nested objects). Thanks for that link to the discussion of lenses, I'll dig in!

Comment: Ah, I missed the point.  I find it an odd case, saying I have a list of lenses and I want to apply this same function to all of them, but I can imagine there are times it's useful.  I don't think there is any way you will be able to do this with lenses without the intermediate objects.  You know that `evolve` works recursively, right?  For example, `evolve ({a: inc, b: {c: dec, d: sum}}) ({a: 5, b: {c: 42, d: [1, 2, 3]}}) //=> {a: 6, {b: {c: 41, d: 6}}}`.

Comment: Evolve is definitely powerful enough to do what I want, but I think I'd need to re-write a bunch of stuff (The way I use it is pretty flat anyhow, so it wouldn't be too hard. I just didn't think of arrays as objects with numeric keys when I started). Also, this is all academic anyway so there's value in convincing myself you're right about lenses. I feel as though as long as what I'm setting and getting is somehow isomorphic (vis-a-vis your farenLens example), I can get (construct) an object from disparate locations in a data structure and set an object into disparate locations too.

Comment: I've made a go at answering my own question. In effect, I do think you're right.

Comment: Updated (yesterday, sorry, forgot to comment) with a discussion about how lenses *can* modify multiple fields, in a restricted, but useful manner.

Answer (score 2):

### What I've Learned So Far

This is probably not a geat idea. The problem is that lenses need to have certain properties to work. One of those properties is this:

> **view(lens, set(lens, a, store)) ≡ a** — If you set a value into the store, and immediately view the value through the lens, you get the value that was set.

If you want a lens to point at multiple values without further restrictions, then that information must be encoded (somehow) in the data structure being altered. If a key is set to an array, that array encodes it's own size. But if setting an array actually corresponds to setting `something else`, then some subset of that `something else` must be isomorphic to arrays (grow, shrink, re-order, the whole shebang). So that you can always convert back and forth.

If you're happy with further restrictions you can do a bit more, but the results are lackluster.

Here's a fully functioning (as far as I can see) lens implemention that points to multple properties but restricts the properties you're allowed to set.

```js
const subsetOf = pipe(without, length, equals(0));
const subset = flip(subsetOf);

const lensProps = propNames => lens(
  pick(propNames),
  (update, data) => 
    subset(keys(update), propNames) ?
    ({ ...data, ...update }) :
    call(() => {throw new Error("OH NO! LENS LAW BROKEN!");})
);
```

In use:

```js
const annualLens = lensProps(["yearsPlayed", "age"]);

const timmy = {
  jersey: 148,
  age: 10,
  yearsPlayed: 2,
  id: 3.14159
};

console.log(
  "View Timmy's Annual Props: ", 
  view(annualLens, timmy)
);
console.log(
  "Set Timmy's Annual Props: ", 
  set(annualLens, {yearsPlayed: 100, age: 108}, timmy)
);
console.log(
  "Update Timmy's Annual Props: ", 
  over(annualLens, map(inc), timmy)
);

// Break the LAW
set(annualLens, {newKey: "HelloWorld"}, timmy);
```

The output:

```html
View Timmy's Annual Props: { age: 10, yearsPlayed: 2 }
Set Timmy's Annual Props: { jersey: 148, age: 108, yearsPlayed: 100, id: 3.14159 }
Update Timmy's Annual Props: { jersey: 148, age: 11, yearsPlayed: 3, id: 3.14159 }
Error: OH NO! LENS LAW BROKEN!
```

---

You could imagine writting a version of this that takes pathes instead of names, but that doesn't actually help since then in order to use `set`, you'd need to know the paths that the lens is expecting to `set`.

It gets worse though. You can compose these sorts of lenses, but there really isn't any point to it:

```js
compose(lensIndex(0), lensProps(["a","b"]), lensProp("b"))
```

is the same as

```js
compose(lensIndex(0), lensProp("b"))
```

So while it doesn't break anything, it quickly becomes profoundly uninteresting. Its only use, really, is as the *'outermost'* lens in a composition. Even then it likely must be constrained to be useful.

As an upside, as the outmost lens, it can actually change multiple values without intermediate objects. This isn't great though, as you can use `evolve` as a function you pass to `over` and you bake in extra functionality without really losing anything.

Comment: I think this is right.  But see the update to my answer for further explanations of how you can use lenses to go after synthetic properties of an object, perhaps involving multiple fields.

Comment: A minor note: the first function you pass to `lens` in `lensProps` is available in Ramda as `pick`, used as `const lensProps = propNames => lens (pick (propNames), <setter>)`.